# How to remove this margin?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/desytec/73qdtejg/1/#&togetherjs=w3lvLQi0v6

That shows this table definition:

```
                               <table id="semana" class="table table-striped dt-responsive table-bordered display nowrap table-hover mb-0 mr-0" style="width: 60%;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width: 40%"><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_0" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_0" class="cr mb-0">Día</label></div></th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 30%">Hora Inicio</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 30%">Hora Término</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_1" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_1" class="cr mb-0">Lunes</label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_2" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_2" class="cr mb-0">Martes</label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_3" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_3" class="cr mb-0">Miércoles</label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_4" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_4" class="cr mb-0">Jueves</label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_5" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_5" class="cr mb-0">Viernes</label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_6" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_6" class="cr mb-0">Sábado</label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_0" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_0" class="cr mb-0">Domingo</label></div></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

I need the shown table to be horizontally centered, but it did not work. I have realized that the table has a huge margin to the right I need to remove so that the table can be centered.

I tried to find that margin using developer tools of Google Chrome but it did not reveal which class adds that margin. As you see, I added mr-0 to the table without success.

Any help?

Thanks

Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this table style:

```
table{
width: 50%; // or can define fix width like 400 or 500 px
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
#semana{
width: 50%;  
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="semana" class="table table-striped dt-responsive table-bordered display nowrap table-hover" style="width: 60%;">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="width: 40%"><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_0" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_0" class="cr mb-0">Día</label></div></th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 30%">Hora Inicio</th>
                                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 30%">Hora Término</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_1" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_1" class="cr mb-0">Lunes</label></div></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_2" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_2" class="cr mb-0">Martes</label></div></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_3" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_3" class="cr mb-0">Miércoles</label></div></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_4" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_4" class="cr mb-0">Jueves</label></div></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_5" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_5" class="cr mb-0">Viernes</label></div></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_6" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_6" class="cr mb-0">Sábado</label></div></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><div class="checkbox d-inline m-0 p-0"><input id="chkSem_0" type="checkbox"><label for="chkSem_0" class="cr mb-0">Domingo</label></div></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraInicio" maxlength="5" name="HoraInicio" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="HoraTermino" maxlength="5" name="HoraTermino" style="display: inline; width: 80%" type="text" value="12:47">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```